# jQuery: Showing a hidden div on page scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery

```
function showDiv() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.lock').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('.lock').fadeOut('slow');
    });
}
$(window).scroll(showDiv);
showDiv();
```

HTML (.lock { display: none; position: fixed; })

```
<div class="lock">
    Text
</div>
```

I'm trying to get a hidden fixed div to appear when you scroll to a certain part of the page, and to disappear when you scroll back up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a syntax issue

```
function showDiv() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.lock').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('.lock').fadeOut('slow');
    }//); <-- drop this close parenthesis/semicolon
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/MFUw3/)

Answer (score 1):

please test this:
put styles in the div.lock element.

```
<div class="lock" style="display: none; position: fixed;">
    Text
</div>
```